# Mysterious "Installation Failed" and reboots

Tags: installation, reboot

Non-programmer here. I've noticed recently a message popping up on my 4.1.2 Galaxy S3 running stock firmware (except I have root)  build number JZO54K.T999UVDMD5. This was happening before I rooted it and before I installed DroidWall in an attempt to prevent any uncommanded activity. "Installation Failed" is what it says.  I've also happened to have observed it restarting a few times when I was not touching it. I installed aLogcat today and set it to "Events" so that hopefully I will get more information. Any suggestions on how to learn more about what's up would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think aLogcat will be able to work on your device since you're running JellyBean. Android stops apps seeing each other's log entries from 4.1 I think, if you convert it to a system app then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the irrelevant answer to the OP's question but felt a need to point out about aLogCat.

**aLogcat** seems broken at the moment under JellyBean (due to an additional introduction of permission `READ_LOGS` required for reading logs).

Just keep an eye out for the update soon (or flag the developer by starring the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/issues/detail?id=41)).

If you fancy the alternative, try this version called **CatLog** found here on [github](https://github.com/nolanlawson/Catlog), this has the permission in place to do so.

As for Droidwall, forget about that version - its old and obsoleted in favour of the more updated version [AFWall+](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall), the linky to the play store version is contained on the github page, alternative linky to F-Droid Repository [here](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=dev.ukanth.ufirewall).